# iOS asking for bluetooth permission even before the package is used

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-permissions

I'm using `react-native-beacons-manager` (https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager to scan beacons nearby using my react native app. It works perfectly but the issue is in iOS, it asks for bluetooth permission right when the app launches. But i only use this package in a screen where it's not loaded on app launch. In Android however it works as expected. It asks for permission only when i visit that screen.

What could be the reason for this and how can i fix this issue?

Comment: You must be triggering the `init` of the `RNiBeacon` class somewhere since that units an `ESSBeaconScanner` which creates an instance of `CBCentralManager` which will trigger the Bluetooth permission dialog.

Comment: @Paulw11 A Fix has been given in this https://github.com/martinmanzo/react-native-beacons-manager but i cannot get this fork to work. It gives some errors when trying to run the app.